# Deprecation or replacing

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrases

<s>I co-manage a PtokaX based DC++ hub in my college.(Only relevant if you know what DC++ and hubs are)</s> We had a script which registered a bot named **`Infobot`** to the hub. Since, those scripts were getting slower because of very bad programming skills and also, I had some newer features to implement, I rewrote the entire script and created another bot with the name **`[BOT]Info`**.

The prefix `[BOT]` is to maintain uniformity across a wide list of users. Now, to inform all the users about this change, I am mentioning:

> Infobot has been **deprecated**. | Comments welcome at `<forum link here>`

My question is, **am I correct in using the word *`deprecated`* here?** Or should I instead be using *replaced* as follows:

> [BOT]Info has **replaced** Infobot. | Comments...

as the older script has been deleted. In my opinion, I'd be using the word *deprecated* when I'm telling about this change to another co-managers of the hub(?) and *replaced* should be preferred word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deprecated means that it is still available for use but it is recommended to use the newer functionality. Deprecated functionality is typically removed after an adequate period of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write :

Infobot **is moved to** [BOT]Info.|Comments....

OR

Infobot **has been moved to** [BOT]Info.|Comments....

Comment: The thing with *moved to* in reference to bots is that they both shared same commands/features. I have introduced a lot of newer commands. Would using *`moved to`* still be applicable?

Comment: @hjpotter92: Jim's comment has already covered your question (if the older bot can still be used, it's *deprecated*; if it can't, you've *replaced* it). Where you "put" these bots, and what terms you might use to describe their "placement", are really a separate question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, I missed the comment. Clicked on the answers notification in inbox.